# User's home folder displayed as UsersFiles

Tags: user-profiles

My user's name is iSYan. When I go to the iSYan system folder on my desktop, it's named "UsersFiles". I have Windows 7 (I know, I still use Windows 7). How can I rename it back to iSYan?

Comment: You may have a incorrect icon. Most likely you are trying to get to C:\Users\Isyan Make a shortcut to this folder on your desktop and use it.

Comment: So, I can't make it display iSYan again?

Comment: There is no " iSYan system folder on my desktop" it does not really exist. Instead, in the background, mydocuments, my desktop, etc. are pointers to things inside of the c:\users  This was done in part for backward compatibility reasons. What happens when you right click it?  Where do you end up? Are you looking at a folder or shortcut properties? If so, rename it.  Something else, then no, make your own shortcut.

Comment: I get these options:

Comment: Open, Open in new window, include in library, copy, create shortcut, delete

Comment: If you open in new window, what is there? What are you looking for that you are using this shortcut to reach?

Comment: Basically, all I want is to rename the system shortcut because the actual folder is ok but the shortcut is named "UsersFiles"

Comment: without a properties or a rename option, unless you got the sys internal tools and used the tweak editor, it is not possible.

Comment: Where can I get those?

Comment: google search, Microsoft owns systeminternals.